# Problemas con AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

estoy trabajando en un proyecto web en el cual necesito realizar un procedimiento almacenado en una base de datos en un momento dado. Pero al intentar ejecutarlo, me da error en una parte del código en la que nunca antes había dado error. Supongo que el error está en el script que he creado. A continuación el código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function miFuncion(){
        var variableJava = 5;
        var objXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var funciona = 0;

        objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var funciona = 1;
            }
        }
        objXMLHttpRequest.open('GET', 'documentoPhp.php?v=' + variableJava);
        objXMLHttpRequest.send();

        <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['v'])) {
            $variable=$_GET['v'];

            $salida = $db->query("CALL miProcedimiento(" . $datosSql['datos'] . "," . $variable . ",@salida);");
            echo ($salida);
        }
        exit;
        ?>
    }

</script>
```

Esta es la pieza de código que da problemas. Si la elimino, todo funciona bien pero si no, da el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null at HTMLDocument. (script.js:46)

Si alguien sabe cual es el error, agradecería que me ayudara.

Comment: El código PHP que muestras debe estar en otro documento distinto llamado documentoPhp.php. Si todo el código esta en ese "documentoPhp.php ", se podria estar llamando a si mismo constantemente y no parece que el código esté pensado para eso.

Comment: ¿Por qué ha código PHP dentro de la función de javascript? ¿Se supone que el que espera la llamada Ajax enviada líneas arriba?

Comment: El error está ocurriendo en la línea `46` de un archivo llamado `script.js`  ¿El código que muestras en la pregunta es de ese archivo (`script.js`)? ¿Cuál es la línea `46`? La llamada a `getContext` no aparece en tu código, por lo que no estás compartiendo en la pregunta el código donde ocurre el error. Es preciso ser lo más claro posible cuando planteas una pregunta y saber interpretar los mensajes de error. Es claro lo que te está diciendo: **`Cannot read property 'getContext' of null at HTMLDocument. (script.js:46)`**

Comment: Sé que está ocurriendo en la línea 46, pero el problema se origina cuando se agrega esa pieza de código. Sin esa pieza de código, no hay problemas en línea 46 y funciona como debería, así que he supuesto que el problema tiene que ser de esta parte del código

Comment: Si `$salida` no es código javascript deberías imprimirlo en `<body>`. (y si es, deberías cerrar `</script>`)

Comment: A ver, el **error** es que el elemento al que quieres aplicar `getContext` en la línea `46` del archivo `script.js`  es nulo. Si no vemos qué objeto es ese, cómo lo obtienes, etc, no podremos ayudarte. Como bien dices, si quitas esa pieza de código el problema se resuelve. Bien, entonces deja quitada esa pieza de código. Nooo, porque necesito esa pieza de código. Ahhh entonces el problema no se resuelve. El problema sigue estando en la línea 46 de `script.js`. Pues muéstranos ese contexto, y si es contenido utlraconfidencial, pon datos ficticios. Sin ver el contexto real es difícil ayudarte.